# How to display Posts via the Category in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, view, posts

This is my first laravel Application, and my first database based application so please be patient with me !!
I will try to be specific!!

Categories Table:
Id 
Name
Timestamps

Posts table:
Id
title
body
slug
Category_id
timestamps

Lets say i have 4 catergories. 
Laptops, computers,phones,tablets

I want when i go to /computers to be able to get all the posts that are specific to that category.

[Posts Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtPce.png)

[Category Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElVEF.png)

**Category Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Category;

class CatController extends Controller
{
   public function getCategory($Category_id)
{
   $posts = Post::where('Category_id',$Category_id);
  return view('blog.index',['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('computer/{Category_id}','CatController@getCategory');
```

I am really confused at the moment !!
Thanks everyone in advance!!

Comment: Try `$posts = DB::table('posts')->where('Category_id', $Category_id)->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Define your Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the posts.
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'Category_id');
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the category.
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'Category_id');
    }
}
```

Define your Controller

```
class CatController extends Controller
{
    public function getCategory($Category_id)
    {
        $category = Category::find($Category_id);
        if($category !== null){
            $posts = $category->posts;
            return view('blog.index',['posts' => $posts]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did what u said ...If i pass in the $Category_id on the controller i get a blank pages 
but if i dont pass in the $Category_id and go with $Category=Category::find(1); 
I get all the post that are in one of my categories but then it doesnt matter what category i go too, it always displays the post under that one category.

Comment: @TasosTogr Please show your route. Please configure your route with something like this: `Route::get('category/{Category_id}', 'CatController@ getCategory')->where('Category_id', '[0-9]+');`

Comment: Route::get('computer/{id}',['uses'=>'CatController@show', 'as' => 'pages.computer-id']);  This is the route i am using but as i told u If i keep the Category_id in the controller i get a blank page

Comment: @TasosTogr Change your Route to: `Route::get('computer/{Category_id}',['uses'=>'CatController@show', 'as' => 'pages.computer-id'])->where('Category_id', '[0-9]+');`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

Route:

```
Route::get('categories/{category_id}/computers','CatController@show');
```

Controller:

```
public function show($category_id)
{
   $category = Category::findOrFail($category_id);

    if($category){
       $posts = Post::where('Category_id',$category_id)->get();

        return view('category.index', compact('posts'));
    }

    return view('errors.404');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your controller

```
public function category($id){


  $data['posts'] = Post::where('status', 1)->where('category_id', $id)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

  return view('frontEnd.home', $data);
}
```